Cannot figure out what setting is locked on my object
I have an appended object I brought into my blender file and at first I was able to enter Edit mode and change the material on it, but something is not allowing me to add a material or even enter Edit Mode, just give an error when I toggle to Edit Mode, and the material '+' button is not clickable. Is there some setting that accidentally hit to trigger this?

Hello could you please share your file or at least show a screenshot?

Without any details or an image of your Blender window it's difficult to tell, but as @moonboots says please share your file which you can do  via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Try appending a new version of the problem object into the scene and see if the problem also exists for that one. If the problem does not exist for that one, delete the other version of the object and call it good.
